# Null pointer exception on Adapter filtering

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-adapter

I want to simply filter my listViews's items by an EditText, i do this with ArrayAdapter implementing Filterable but for some reason i got a massive NullPointerException...
I did this by some tutorials and i just cant figure it out what is the problem i tried to try catch everything in my code but i just cant make it work.

When i try to type text to my EditText, it is freezes then i got the crash:

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks.

```
07-06 11:35:15.785: E/AndroidRuntime(28779): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-06 11:35:15.785: E/AndroidRuntime(28779): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-06 11:35:15.785: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at com.KeySoft.OpenGuide.Adapter.SearchAdapter.getView(SearchAdapter.java:61)
07-06 11:35:15.785: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1533)
07-06 11:35:15.785: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1793)
07-06 11:35:15.785: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1338)
07-06 11:35:15.785: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1624)
07-06 11:35:15.785: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1384)
07-06 11:35:15.785: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7228)
07-06 11:35:15.785: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:912)
07-06 11:35:15.785: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7228)
07-06 11:35:15.785: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
07-06 11:35:15.785: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
07-06 11:35:15.785: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
07-06 11:35:15.785: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7228)
07-06 11:35:15.785: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
07-06 11:35:15.785: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7228)
07-06 11:35:15.785: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
07-06 11:35:15.785: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7228)
07-06 11:35:15.785: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1145)
07-06 11:35:15.785: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1865)
07-06 11:35:15.785: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-06 11:35:15.785: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-06 11:35:15.785: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
07-06 11:35:15.785: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-06 11:35:15.785: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-06 11:35:15.785: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
07-06 11:35:15.785: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
07-06 11:35:15.785: E/AndroidRuntime(28779):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Here is my Adapter with Filterable:**

```
public class SearchAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<KeresesBejegyzes> implements Filterable

{

private Activity context;
private List<KeresesBejegyzes> bejegyzesek;
private List<KeresesBejegyzes> eredetiBejegyzesek;

static class ViewHolder
{
    public TextView shopNameTv;
    public TextView shopTavTv;
}

public SearchAdapter(Activity context, List<KeresesBejegyzes> bejegyzesek_)
{
    super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, bejegyzesek_);
    this.context = context;
    this.bejegyzesek = bejegyzesek_;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View rowView = convertView;

    if (rowView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.shopNameTv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.shopNameTv);
        viewHolder.shopTavTv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tavTv);

        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();

    KeresesBejegyzes bejegyzes = bejegyzesek.get(position);

    holder.shopNameTv.setText(bejegyzes.getNev());

    if (bejegyzes.getTavolsag() != 0)
    {
        holder.shopTavTv.setText(Double.toString(bejegyzes.getTavolsag()) + " km - " + bejegyzes.getTipus());
    }
    else
    {
        holder.shopTavTv.setText(bejegyzes.getTipus());
    }

    return rowView;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter()
{

    try
    {

        Filter filter = new Filter()
        {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results)
            {

                bejegyzesek = (List<KeresesBejegyzes>) results.values; // has
                                                                        // the
                                                                        // filtered
                                                                        // values
                notifyDataSetChanged(); // notifies the data with new
                                        // filtered values
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint)
            {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults(); // Holds the
                                                                // results
                                                                // of a
                                                                // filtering
                                                                // operation
                                                                // in values
                List<KeresesBejegyzes> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<KeresesBejegyzes>();

                if (eredetiBejegyzesek == null)
                {
                    eredetiBejegyzesek = new ArrayList<KeresesBejegyzes>(bejegyzesek); // saves
                                                                                        // the
                                                                                        // original
                                                                                        // data
                                                                                        // in
                                                                                        // mOriginalValues
                }

                /********
                 * 
                 * If constraint(CharSequence that is received) is null
                 * returns the mOriginalValues(Original) values else does
                 * the Filtering and returns FilteredArrList(Filtered)
                 * 
                 ********/
                if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0)
                {
                    // set the Original result to return
                    results.count = eredetiBejegyzesek.size();
                    results.values = eredetiBejegyzesek;

                }
                else
                {

                    constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

                    for (int i = 0; i < eredetiBejegyzesek.size(); i++)
                    {
                        KeresesBejegyzes data = eredetiBejegyzesek.get(i);

                        if (data.getNev().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString()) || data.getCim().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString()))
                        {
                            FilteredArrList.add(data);
                        }
                    }
                    // set the Filtered result to return
                    results.count = FilteredArrList.size();
                    results.values = FilteredArrList;

                }
                return results;
            }
        };

        return filter;

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("SearchAdapterError", e.toString());
    }

    return null;

}

}
```

**And this is the EditText:**

```
searchEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
                {
                    try
                    {       
                        if(searchAdapter.getFilter() != null)
                        {
                            searchAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ki("Error 8: searchAdapter.getFilter() == null");
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        ki("Error 7:"+e);
                    }

                }

                 @Override
                 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                 }

                 @Override
                 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                 }
            });
```

E D I T for dj aqeel:

I only got null pointer ex when i try to search via EditText, my listView shows my list verry well, i can even sort it, that works well without any exception.

Init:
(I just realized bejegyzesek is not a list, it is a vector, could it be a problem ? It is an old code remaking so i left this unchanged by a mistake..)

So this is in my Activity:

```
public class Search extends Activity 
{

    Vector<KeresesBejegyzes> bejegyzesek = new Vector<KeresesBejegyzes>();


    // (...more code here...)


db.open();
            Cursor c = db.getAllShopsFullTitles();

            if(c.moveToFirst())
            {
                do
                {
                    KeresesBejegyzes kb = new KeresesBejegyzes();

                    kb.setNev(c.getString(1));
                    kb.setTipus(c.getString(2));
                    kb.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(c.getString(4)));
                    kb.setLonditude(Double.parseDouble(c.getString(5)));

                    bejegyzesek.add(kb);

            }while(c.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();

listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
            searchAdapter = new SearchAdapter(this, bejegyzesek);
            listView.setAdapter(searchAdapter);
```

Comment: what line exactly is SearchAdapter.java:61? have you tried putting a break point here and debugging through your code to see exactly where you are getting the Null from?

Comment: Which one is line number 61 in your SearchAdapter file? Please tell us, so that we can look into it.

Comment: It is:bejegyzes.getNev() And if add value to it, i got another exception at: KeresesBejegyzes bejegyzes = bejegyzesek.get(position); These statements are in the getView func... whats next? I dont understand this.

Comment: Ok where this list is initialized? show that code? ie where SearchAdapter is instantiated.

Comment: Check my question i edited it. SearchAdapter is my Activity's class data tag.

Comment: Can you print the contents of the `bejegyzesek` list just before this line `KeresesBejegyzes bejegyzes = bejegyzesek.get(position);`

Comment: I can bet there are some null entries in your list, which are causing null pointer exception

Comment: I tried with this:
for ( int i =0; i<bejegyzesek.size(); i++)
  {
   
   Log.i("YES NIL", bejegyzesek.get(i).toString());
   Log.i("YES NEV", bejegyzesek.get(i).getNev());
   Log.i("YES CIM", bejegyzesek.get(i).getCim());
   
  }

And i got null pointer exception. It is clear that my whole list is null for some reason...

Okay thanks the advice i check the values one by one.

Comment: only print `bejegyzesek.get(i)`, so if there is null entry simply null will be printed. otherwise some other string is printed.

Comment: It is like this:MyPackagName.KeresesBejegyzes@40580898